# Better way for storing database IDs and lookup names

Tags: c#, data-structures, c#-4.0, lookup-tables

I'm currently storing a list of Tests with associated information, including database IDs, inside static variables in my code. Here's an example:

```
public static class IsokineticTests
{
    // Cervical Spine Group
    public static MyopathologyTest NeckFlexors = MyopathologyTest.Create(600, "Neck Flexors");
    public static MyopathologyTest AnteriorObliques = MyopathologyTest.Create(601, "Anterior Obliques");
    public static MyopathologyTest NeckExtensors = MyopathologyTest.Create(602, "Neck Extensors");
    public static MyopathologyTest PosteriorObliques = MyopathologyTest.Create(603, "Posterior Obliques");
    public static MyopathologyTest LateralFlexion = MyopathologyTest.Create(604, "Lateral Flexion");

    // Shoulder Group
    public static MyopathologyTest ShoulderAbductors = MyopathologyTest.Create(610, "Shoulder Abductors");
    public static MyopathologyTest ShoulderExtensors = MyopathologyTest.Create(611, "Shoulder Extensors");
    public static MyopathologyTest ShoulderFlexors = MyopathologyTest.Create(612, "Shoulder Flexors");
    public static MyopathologyTest ShoulderLateralRotators = MyopathologyTest.Create(613, "Shoulder Lateral Rotators");
    public static MyopathologyTest ShoulderMedialRotators = MyopathologyTest.Create(614, "Shoulder Medial Rotators");
}
```

These then get used to create a test group through other static properties get methods:

```
public static class IsokineticTestGroups
{
    public static IsokineticTestGroup CervicalSpine
    {
        get
        {
            return IsokineticTestGroup.Create("Cervical Spine", 
                    new List<MyopathologyTest>
                       {
                            IsokineticTests.NeckFlexors,
                            IsokineticTests.AnteriorObliques, 
                            IsokineticTests.NeckExtensors,
                            IsokineticTests.PosteriorObliques,
                            IsokineticTests.LateralFlexion
                       });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having now is there is essentially no way to lookup the MyopathologyTest for a specific ID. One solution would be to create a dictionary and manually insert all these tests into the dictionary with the ID as the key. This seems like repeating a lot of code though.

**What is the proper way to be implementing something like this?** I'm thinking I need to externalize the test data, load in the tests during runtime and generate the proper look-up tables and groups on the fly. Is this the right approach I should be looking at or is there a better way?

Comment: Why don't you store all of this data, including the groups, in a database?

Comment: I'm already using a SQLite database for the test results amongst other things, and I suppose my thought was it would make changing some of the data too hard in the future. However, I see no reason I couldn't have a separate database containing this information now that you and Tim mention it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not keep the test information in a database, like SQLite, and fetch the data on an as-needed basis using ADO.NET libraries?  Response time is virtually instantaneous, so you have no need to store many test objects in a dictionary.

Comment: Well, this is an application that will be run client-side. The database IDs reference a TestID field in a SQLite table which stores test results. To initially populate the tests in the database, it would require still storing the tests in code or external then populating the database on initialization, and then adding tests in the future requires updating a user's database. It sounds like this method just becomes more complex. Perhaps I should just store these in a separate database instead...